# Selecting elements inside a frame with a dynamic src and NO id

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to select a value in a dropdown which is inside a iFrame. The frame contains no id but has a src that is dynamic.

```
/MyApplicantPortal/Applicant/244029/SelectOrderTemplate?t=1
```

HTML:

```
<html class = ......>
```

.
    .
    .

the number 244029 changes and because of this, I am not able to identify the objects inside the frame. The iframe is the child of the div.

My code is

```
in_frame(:src => 'MyApplicantPortal/Applicant/244025/SelectOrderTemplate?t=1') do |frame|
select_list(:template, :id => 'selectlisname', :frame => frame)
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Using a regexp**

Contrary to my initial assumption, the `in_frame` method does not support locating a frame using regular expressions ([Issue 197](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/197)). However, it is possible to monkey patch the functionality in. Where you require page-object, add the following code to monkey match the `nested_frames` method.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
module PageObject
  module Platforms
    module WatirWebDriver 
      class PageObject
        def nested_frames(frame_identifiers)
          return if frame_identifiers.nil?
          frame_str = ''
          frame_identifiers.each do |id|
            value = id.values.first
            if value.is_a?(Regexp)
              frame_str += "frame(:#{id.keys.first} => #{value.inspect})." 
            else
              frame_str += "frame(:#{id.keys.first} => #{value})." if value.to_s.is_integer
              frame_str += "frame(:#{id.keys.first} => '#{value}')." unless value.to_s.is_integer
            end
          end
          frame_str
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This then allows you to use a regular expression to define the src of the frame (when using `in_frame`):

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_frame(:src =>  /MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/) do |frame|
    select_list(:template, :id => 'selectlisname', :frame => frame)
  end
end
```

Note that in a regexp, you need to escape the characters `\*?{}.`. The `\d+` part means that any number will be matched.

**Solution 2 - Define a frame_element**

If you do not want to monkey patch the page object gem, then you could:

1. Define the frame element (using the regular expression)
2. Use a block, which references the frame element, to define the select list

This would look like:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  element(:select_order, :frame, :src => /MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/)
  select_list(:template){ select_order_element.select_list_element(:id => 'selectlisname') }
end
```

Comment: I get an error message: Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate frame/iframe using {:src=>"(?-mix:\\/MyApplicantPortal\\/Applicant\\/\\d+\\/SelectOrderTemplate\\?t=1)"}
(eval):1:in `process_watir_call'

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested my initial assumption about `in_frame` supporting regular expressions. I have updated the answer to (1) include a monkey patch that will allow my initial suggestion to work as well as (2) an alternative approach if monkey patching is not desired.

Comment: It errors out when I use the { ... (syntax error)  I did change it to ( but still...

Comment: Are you trying the second approach? There was a missing bracket after `:template`. It has been updated (hopefully that is the last of the typos).

Comment: Yes I did choose the second option. That worked! Thank you so much Justin.But I do get a warning as below:*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named select_list at D:/Mytest/MyApplication/features/pages/select_quote_template_auto.rb:7:in `block in <class:SelectQuoteTemplatePage>'.
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
*** Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.

Comment: In the block, did you do `select_list` instead of `select_list_element` (see the example)?

Comment: Yeah..one of the lines had it. I changed it to select_list_element and it worked just fine. Thank you again!

Comment: This was was working without any problem for a while but now I am getting `Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate frame using {:src=>/MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/, :tag_name=>"frame"} ` . I updated my page-object gem. I also think that the frame appears under a div with id ="ui-id-2" now...I am not sure how it was earlier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the frame src has not changed? You should also verify that the frame has not been moved inside another frame.

Comment: The frame src has not changed. It is src="/MyApplicantPortal/Applicant/254471/SelectOrderTemplate?t=1" .The frame also has not moved under any other frame.But there is a HTML section under the iFrame tag. and the select list is under a table within td tags.

Comment: HTML `<html class ="some text">
<head>...</head>
<body id="htmlBody">
<div class= "modalWindow ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ModalWindow containsFrame" id="ui-id-2">
<iframe src= "/MyApplicantPortal/Applicant/254471/SelectOrderTemplate?t=1">
 #document
 <html class = "some text"
   <head id= "Head1">
   <body id="htmlBody">
   <form method= "post" action="SelectQuoteTemplate?t=1" id="form1">
    <div class = "ModalContent">
 <Table>
  <td class="label1">
    <Select id= "selectlisname" 
         </td>`

Comment: Which solution (from this answer) are you using? If using Solution 1, you should make sure that you removed the patch given that the code is corrected in the latest page-object gem. Other than that, I would suggest creating a new question with all of the needed information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I actually tried both. I will create a new question with the HTML details.Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533962/accessing-elements-from-within-a-iframe

Comment: I finally found a root cause of the failure. The Watir-Webdriver causes this to fail. I reverted back to watir-webdriver 0.6.4 and it worked fine. Watir-webdriver 0.6.6 causes the failure. Not sure what has changed between the 2 versions.